# I am trying to decompress a file that I created

Tags: python

My code has a file "filefile.txt" which has a compressed sentence in it. The file is laid out like :

```
1
2
3 
4
5
1
2
6
9
10
11
2
12
12
9

This 
is
a 
sentence
.
too   
!
Yo
yo
bling
```

The original text that I want to decompress says "!"

My code says:

```
fo = open("filefile.txt","r")
script = fo.readline()
script2 = fo.readline()
fo.close()
script2 = script2.split()
script = [s.strip("\n") for s in script]

sentencewords = []

while len(script) > 0:
    for p in script:
        sentencewords.append(enumerate(script2.index(p)))
        script.remove(0)

print(sentencewords)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\code attempts\AT13.py", line 46, in <module>
    sentencewords.append(enumerate(script2.index(p)))
ValueError: '1' is not in list
```

I need `sentencewords` to contain "This is a sentence. This is too! Yo yo bling bling!"

I have changed it now but it still doesn't work.
        sentencewords.append(enumerate(script2.enumerate(p)))

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "F:\code attempts\AT13.py", line 46, in 
    sentencewords.append(enumerate(script2.enumerate(p)))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'enumerate''

Does anyone know if there is another way round this problem or how to fix my current code?

```
fo = open("filefile.txt","r")
script = fo.readline()
script2 = fo.readline()
fo.close()
script2 = script2.split()
script = [s.strip("\n") for s in script]

sentencewords = []

indexes = []
for line in fo:
    if line.strip().isdigit():
        indexes.append(line)
    else:
        break


words = [line.strip() for line in fo if line.strip()]

while len(script) > 0:
    for p in script:
        sentencewords.append(words[index-1])


print(sentencewords)
```

Updated code but I don't know what the I/O thing means in the latest output from python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/code attempts/attempt14.py", line 45, in <module>
    for line in fo:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

fo.close() has been moved further down the code and now it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\code attempts\attempt14.py", line 55, in <module>
sentencewords.append(words[index-1])
MemoryError
```

Any suggestions on how to fix my code, I'd be grateful for

thanks

Comment: It throws that error because you have already closed file "fo" before trying to loop through it.

Comment: ........Thank you......

Answer (score 0):

Format the text file in a better way and it will be easier to deal with.

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 6 9 10 11 2 12 12 9
This is a sentence. too ! Yo yo bling
```

Then do this...

```
script = []
sentencewords = []
with open("filefile.txt", "r") as fo:
    for line in fo:
        script.append(line.strip("\n").split(" "))
    for i in script[0]:
        sentencewords.append(script[1][int(i)-1])
print(sentencewords)
```

Your indices above 10 will give issues though, because you don't have that many words.